# Minimum set of portable Git binary files(for Windows) for `clone` and `pull` only

Tags: git

I'd like to implement a Windows application which clones/pulls my remote git repository via dumb HTTP(`clone` and `pull` only).
To achieve this, I decided to put Git portable binaries in my application package, and my application will execute `git.exe` as a child process for '`git clone`' or '`git pull`' commands.
But the size of Git portable binaries from the official download site('https://git-scm.com/download/win') is over 200 MB, too large for my application.

Is it inevitable to execute any git command?
Or, can I extract a minimum set of binaries files, e.g., `git.exe` and some dlls, especially for `clone` and `pull` only?

**P.S.**
`libgit2` is not an option for me because it works with `smart HTTP` only, NOT with `dumb HTTP`.

Comment: You can just take [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and check which files are used in your commands. I suspect you can save very much.

Comment: @max630: Yes, I'm trying as you suggested, but I expect anyone already had done this job prior to me..

Comment: I found some clue by googling: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/msysgit/BugV7r6eFyY/HljgvGph218J

Comment: This also looks helpful, maybe: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Why-Is--libexec--so-huge%3F

Comment: It can be obsolete for recent git version. For example, `git pull` used to be shell script before 2.6.0, so you would have to use shell with its dependencies, but now you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your case is the one which would benefit from [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/)

Comment: I had also tried `libgit2` at first, but it doesn't run with `dumb HTTP` . could you please share any other library with me, if available?